# how to convert touchscreen raw x and raw y on Android

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I write C code to read /dev/input/event0 and then I read the rawX and rawY,
but in Activity OnTouch function, I get x and y they don't equal rawX and rawY.
I know they have a relationship, but I don't know how to convert. Maybe something in some files can let me convert them?

The C code is like:

```
    while (!is_stop) {
        read(fd, &ev, sizeof(struct input_event));
        switch (ev.type) {
            case EV_SYN:
                if(x != 0 && y != 0) {
                    (*env)->SetIntField(env,obj, x_id, x);
                    (*env)->SetIntField(env, obj, y_id, y);
                }
                //LOGI("sync");
                break;
            case EV_KEY:
                if (ev.code == BTN_TOUCH) {
                    if (ev.value == 1) { // finger down
                        LOGI("finger down,keycode is %d keyvalue is %d", ev.code, ev.value);
                    } else if (ev.value == 0) { //finger up,上一次x,y是0
                        finger_up = 1;
                        LOGI("finger up,keycode is %d keyvalue is %d", ev.code, ev.value);
                    }
                }
               break;
            case EV_ABS:
                if (ev.code == ABS_X) {
                    LOGI("abs_x:%d\n", ev.value);
                    x = ev.value;
                }
                else if (ev.code == ABS_Y) {
                    LOGI("abs_y:%d\n", ev.value);
                    y = ev.value;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        is_stop = (*env)->GetBooleanField(env, obj, stop_id);
    }
    close(fd);
```

and the java code like

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getRawY();
    float y = event.getRawX();
    Log.i(TAG, "x = " + x + " y = " + y);
    if (marker != null) {
        int xy[] = marker.getLocation();
        Log.i(TAG, "rawx = " + xy[0] + " rawy = " + xy[1]);
    }
            // the rawx != x and rawy != y ,how to convert?

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

can some one help?

Comment: If this is in C why have you tagged it with Java?

Comment: From what I just read about JNI this is just a way to let you call C or C++ from Java or execute a JVM instance from C or C++. So why not tag it with JNI and C?

Comment: sorry,I get it,thanks for your advice